# Javascript capitalize string with hyphen

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, object

I've array of string and want to make it capitalize.
have looped to the array of strings and want to make first letter and letter after hyphen capitalize and remove hyphen

```js
locales= ['es-US', 'en-US', 'en-CA', 'fr-CA', 'ar', 'fi', 'hy']

for(const st of locales) {
   const basePkg = `locale${st.replace(/(-.)/g,function(x){return x[1].toUpperCase()})}`;
   console.log(basePkg); // I get output as ['localeesUS', 'localeenUS', 'localeenCA', 'localefrCA', 'localear', 'localefi', 'localehy'] 
}
```

Required output should be

```
['localeEsUS', 'localeEnUS', 'localeEnCA', 'localeFrCA', 'localeAr', 'localeFi', 'localeHy']
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `replace` for the first character:

```
st.replace(/(-.)/g, x => x[1].toUpperCase()).replace(/^./, x => x.toUpperCase())
```

Example:

```js
const locales = ['es-US', 'en-US', 'en-CA', 'fr-CA', 'ar', 'fi', 'hy']

console.log(locales.map(st => `locale${st.replace(/(-.)/g, x => x[1].toUpperCase()).replace(/^./, x => x.toUpperCase())}`));
```